# how remove string 'undefined' from cycle output?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

please help solve the problem.

on the page([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h6w7har1/)) displays 4 news containers. but before first news container output string 'undefined'. i need remove string 'undefined'

html:

```
<div class="banners__wrap-article" id='sk_wrap_82630'></div>
```

js:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById('sk_wrap_82630').innerHTML = '<div class="banners__smi2"> \
            <div class="banners__smi2__header"><span class="banners__smi2__header-text">Новости</span></div> \
            ' + cycleItems() + ' \
            </div> \
            <div class="banners__smi2"> \
                <div class="banners__smi2__header"><span class="banners__smi2__header-text"></span></div> \
            </div>';                
    }
}

function cycleItems(){
    var items;
    var massive = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { 
        items = items + constructItem(massive.news[i].url, massive.news[i].img, massive.news[i].title) 
    };

    return items;
}

function constructItem(url, img, title){
    var item;

    return '<div class="banners__smi2__item"> \
                <a href="' + url + '" class="banners__smi2__link"> \
                    <img class="banners__smi2__img" src="' + img + '" alt="" /> \
                    <span class="banners__smi2__title">' + title + '</span> \
                </a> \
            </div>';
}
```

Comment: Please define your variable: var items = ' ';         [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/h6w7har1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize variable `items` to empty string in function `cycleItems()`. like

```
 var items = '';
```

Check this jsfiddle.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6w7har1/2/)